# How to change the order of authors in citation

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I'm trying to make a citation which list multiple articles and I want them to be sorted in the order I provide them in the \citep{} command. However latex seems to change them to alphabetical order..

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside]{article} 

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}


\citep{zen2001, all2004, chez2007}


\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

This would give an output like this: (All 2004, Chez 2007, Zen 2001)
While I want it to be in the order I put it in the command like this (Zen 2001, All 2004, Chez 2007)

I only want the order to be chronologic in the citation and not in the actual reference list where I do want it to be sorted alphabetically. Hopefully there is someone who can help.

Comment: Real quick: Are you loading the `natbib` package with the option `sort` (or `sort&compress`)? If so, drop that option.

Comment: From the editorial perspective, Harvard style requires that the Reference List or Bibliography list the works by the authors' last names, regardless of the type of material (books, journals, etc.). If there are several works from one author or source, those works should be listed together chronologically. The same is true for inline citations. If your document calls for Harvard style, don't break the style rules unless your document also requires reverse alphabetical or reverse chronological order (your example could be either one) citations and reference list.

Comment: You shouldn't load `cite` along with `natbib`.

Comment: Thnx! Removing cite worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired format of the citation call-outs, you need to write

```
(\citealt{zen2001, all2004, chez2007})
```

Since the `agsm` style is part of the `harvard` citation management package, you should also load the `har2nat` package to assure full compatibility with `natbib`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zen2001,
  author  = "Zoe Zen",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 2001,
  volume  = 1,
} 
@article{all2004,
  author  = "Anna All",
  title   = "Further Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 2004,
  volume  = 4,
}
@article{chez2007,
  author  = "Chad Chez",
  title   = "Final Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 2007,
  volume  = 7,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,}}  % not required, but useful to state anyway
\usepackage{har2nat} % emulate macros of "harvard" package
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
(\citealt{zen2001, all2004, chez2007})
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```